# PostGIS ST_AsTIFF function raises memory exception?

Tags: postgis, export, geotiff-tiff

We have a satellite image loaded into PostGIS.  We've calculated a reflectance raster from that image and stored the results as 32BF pixels.  There are 54 1000x1000 tiles in the reflectance raster.

I want to create a GeoTIFF of that reflectance raster.  Individual tiles work fine.  But using an ST_Union on the reflectance raster column raises an exception when executing the query below from Python:

```
SELECT ST_AsTIFF(ST_Union(refl_rast), 'GTiff') gtiff
FROM sat_rast_calc

InternalError: invalid memory alloc request size 1344128795
```

I know I can export the tiles individually and merge them with gdal_merge.py afterwards.  I'd prefer to export this GTiff in one step though.

Would any of these be likely to help?

1. Using a different pixel type
2. Passing in another ST_AsGTIFF option
3. Increasing a PostGRES memory parameter
4. Increasing a Linux kernel parameter
5. Doing something else

Comment: 1344128795 bytes are actually 1.3 gigabytes

Answer (score 1):

The in-memory limit for one row in PostgreSQL is 1 GB. Try using a less memory hungry pixel type. You can also try to pass a compression parameter to ST_AsTiff() but I think internal work is done without compression. Try also to compress tiles BEFORE ST_Union() them just in case... Rasters in PostGIS are desinged to work well as small raster chunk. Not to manipulate big rasters as a whole.

Comment: I don't like the solution of raising the memory limit.  Ram should be treated as a temporary place and certainly not the best place of  putting petabytes of data.